# NSSetで動的に複数セットしたい

Tags: ios, swift

NSSetで
    NSSet(objects: "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
とセットしたく、ただし列挙部分は動的に生成したい場合、
swiftではどのように列挙部分を生成すればよろしいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下でどうでしょうか？

```
// NSSet を作る際に array を使用して、その引数を動的に変更する方法
var mary = ["aaa", "bbb"]
mary.append("ccc")
var set = NSSet(array:mary)

// NSMutableSet を使用して、動的に追加する方法
var mset = NSMutableSet(objects:"aaa", "bbb")
mset.addObject("ccc")
```

Comment: 早速ありがとうございました！NSMutableSetを使用することで意図したものができました。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

補足ですが、Swift1.2からはSwift用Setが使えますので、状況が許せば、以下のようにもかけます。

```
var set = Set<String>()
set.insert("aaa")
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回は1.1ですので使用できませんが、ぜひ覚えておきたいと思います。